# When are objects loaded into memory in python?

Tags: python

Take the following example in python:

```
$ python
>>> id(True)
140736139690832
>>> id(1)
140317292515368
>>> ^D

$ python
>>> id(True)
140736139690832
>>> id(1)
140585619968040
```

`True` has the same `id` in both cases but the number `1` does not. Why is this so? Does it assign certain types to a memory address before initializing python, or why are the memory address sometimes the same and sometimes different between different items?

From the docs:

> CPython implementation detail: For CPython, id(x) is the memory address where x is stored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CPython creates reusable storage for small numbers, but presumably it does this in a loop, and stores them into a heap-allocated array of constants.  On the other hand, `True` and `False` are more like "static globals" which have fixed addresses in the Python executable image.

So there's nothing really surprising here.  You shouldn't depend on these details either--`id` is rarely used in real-world Python programs.

Comment: Actually, the `id` of `True` changes between executions, too. OP got the same `id` twice by sheer coincidence.

Comment: @Aran-Fey: That may depend on ASLR, I wouldn't be surprised if OP's `True` actually is loaded at the same address if ASLR is not in play.